# How can a Linux sound problem affect Windows in a dual boot configuration?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, windows, audio, dual-boot

It has now been the third time I got problems with the sound while working on a Linux Os in a dual boot configuration with Windows 10. It happened to me twice under Ubuntu 16.04 and most recently under Debian 9.0.1.

It appears that after any random system suspension and/or lock screen with headphones plugged in, the sound card recognition stops working, and when I unplug and plug the headphones again I no longer get an answer from pulseaudio. After reboot, I get Dummy output in linux's pulseaudio and despite trying many solutions, the only really viable one is to format the disk and make a clean install of both OS. I even tried to restore the disk images and it didn't work.

I wanted to ask how is it possible that a linux sound problem can affect Windows 10 in a different partition, and be persistent over disk image restore? What might be causing this problem?

I have a Dell Inspiron 7560, the sound device is Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21).

Thanks!

Comment: Your details are misleading as no configuration change happens when you plug and unplug headphones.  This means that the only possible change is at a lower level such as plug&play/ACPI/hardware issue.  Can you confirm that the problem happens after you shutdown the computer completely from Linux and reboot into Linux?  Such hardware (plug&play/ACPI) conflicts between OS's are not that uncommon.

Comment: To amplify @JuliePelletier 's comment, "shutdown the computer completely" means "turn off the power for more than a few seconds".